# sh - Using Arguments in .profile functions

Tags: shell, scripting, function, arguments, profile

I want to use an argument in the function I created in my .profile file.

I want to ask for input if no argument is given, otherwise set a variable to $1.

When I check $1 to see if it is empty, I get the following error:

```
sh[7]: 1: Parameter not set.
```

From the following line:

```
if [ ! -n "$1" ]; then
```

I'm using sh not bash.

EDIT: Ok, here is the first line of code until the end of the if statement:

```
HOST=`hostname`
cd /opt/dirpath
ll *.sto


if [ x"$1" = x ]; then
  # Ask for input
  echo "File: \c"; read outFile
else
    outFile=$1
fi
```

I'm editing someone else's code to work with or without arguments.

Comment: the way I've seen this done is `if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then ...` there is no parameter

Comment: As @JeffSchaller points out, the `[[ ... ]]` construct is a `bash` extension, you need to use `if [ x"$1" = x ]` instead.

Comment: Do you use `set -e`?

Comment: James, I see you edited the script to remove square brackets after lcd047's comment. After reading mikeserv's answer, I think it would be worthwhile to see more or all of your .profile so that we know what's going on.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - `$1` is the parameter. The error message says so. It says: `[LINENO]: PARAM_NAME: DEFAULT ERROR MESSAGE.`. Try it. Try: `unset my_var_name; echo "${my_var_name?"My error message."}"`. And to test if a var is set or unset just do `[ -z "${var+.}" ]`

Comment: @James - that's not all. Or else you have `set -u` in the interactive shell otherwise. Somewhere you either do `${1?}` or you do `set -u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's more to this:

Either that's not the command you're using - or else somewhere else in the function you're doing it differently. That error comes from `${1?}`. Or it comes from your test, but only if you first do `set -u`.

To fix that, stop doing that. Do `set +u; fn_name`, and see what happens. And if you have any `${1?}` expansions in there, that error will not go away until you give the function an argument.

Here are some code examples of how you might reproduce that error:

```sh
sh -c 'fn(){ [ ! -n "${1?}" ]; }; fn'
sh: 1: 1: parameter not set
```

...or...

```
sh -uc 'fn(){ [ ! -n "$1" ]; }; fn'
sh: 1: 1: parameter not set
```

...but...

```
sh -uc 'fn(){ [ ! -n "$1" ]; }
        set +u; fn; echo "$?"'
0
```

...and...

```
sh -c 'fn(){ [ ! -n "${1?}" ]; }
       fn some args; echo "$?"'
1
```

If the function is setting `-u` then you should probably edit that out. Or else if your `.profile` is doing so, same goes. In most cases, `set -u` is *not* a desirable persistent shell setting, and this is because that mode is *designed* to kill shells. It does not provide any simple means of handling the kinds of errors it generates - which is what you're trying to do with `[` test `]`.

Comment: @James - I am still very curious - how did it get `set -u`? I can imagine that a curious `man sh` reader might notice it in passing and try it then forget it later... *(it's how I learned of it after all...)* Anyway, you don't need to do that `[ "$1x"` thing - it doesn't actually tell you if you have got an argument or not anyway. You could get a null first arg  and a not-null $2 for example. I think what you want is either `[ -n "${1+.}" ] || echo...` or `[ "$#" = 0 ] && echo ...` And, about `-u` - you can `echo "$-"` to see a list of currently actove shell options anytime.